# Best case to use tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, scikit-learn, regression, linear-regression

I followed all the steps mentioned in the article:

https://stackabuse.com/tensorflow-2-0-solving-classification-and-regression-problems/

Then I compared the results with Linear Regression and found that the error is less (68) than the tensorflow model (84).

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
logreg_clf = LinearRegression()
logreg_clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
pred = logreg_clf.predict(X_test)
print(np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_test, pred)))
```

Does this mean that if I have large dataset, I will get better results than linear regression?
What is the best situation - when I should be using tensorflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering your first question, Neural Networks are notoriously known for [overfitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting) on smaller datasets, and here you are comparing the performance of a simple linear regression model with a neural network with two hidden layers on the testing data set, so it's not very surprising to see that the MLP model falling behind (assuming that you are working with relatively a smaller dataset) the linear regression model. Larger datasets will definitely help neural networks in learning more accurate parameters and generalize the phenomena well.

Now coming to your second question, Tensorflow is basically a library for building deep learning models, so whenever you are working on a deep learning problem like image recognition, Natural Language Processing, etc. you need massive computational power and will be processing a ton of data to train your models, and this is where TensorFlow becomes handy, it offers you GPU support which will significantly boost your training process which otherwise becomes practically impossible. Moreover, if you are building a product that has to be deployed in a production environment for it to be consumed, you can make use of [TensorFlow Serving](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/guide/serving) which helps you to take your models much closer to the customers.